# Azure ARM - Update Management - VMs onboarding

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

I have prepared template for VMs onboarding into Update Management, tasks covered by the ARM: MMA agent installation, connecting VM to workspace. ARM works quite ok, but after deployment there is one additional task to do, I have to manually enable VM in Update Management console. I know that I can enable auto-onboarding in Manage Machines section, but I would like to have control over VMs, and decide what VM will be onboarded or not. My template presented below, is there any method to fully onboard VMs into Update Management using ARM template?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "List of virtual machines to be Lg Analytics Joined joined, if using multiple VMs, make their names comma separate. E.g. VM01, VM02, VM03."
            },
            "defaultValue": "VM1,VM2"
        },
        "Location":{
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the VM"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "WestEurope"
        },

        "OMSWorkspaceResourceGroup":{
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "OMSWorkspace RESOURCE GROUP"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "yourLogAnalyticsRG"
        },
        "omsWorkspacename": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "OMSWorkspaceName"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "YourLoganalyticsworkspacename"
        }
    },
    "variables": {

        "vmListArray": "[split(parameters('vmName'),',')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "LogAnalyticsExtention",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(trim(variables('vmListArray')[copyIndex()]),'/MicrosoftMonitoringAgent')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "ExtentionLooptoAllVMs",
                "count": "[length(variables('vmListArray'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
        "type": "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "workspaceId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('OMSWorkspaceResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkspacename')), '2015-11-01-preview').customerId]"
                },
                "protectedSettings": {
                    "workspaceKey": "[listKeys(resourceId(parameters('OMSWorkspaceResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('omsWorkspacename')),'2015-11-01-preview').primarySharedKey]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have the same question, did you eventually figured out how to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have completed the task. I used default Scope configuration and default Computer query. These two components are being created during enabling Update Management solution from azure portal. Solution works, and if somebody would like to know the detail please contact me.

Comment: `if somebody would like to know the detail please contact me` Please include the details *here* in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management-deploy-template) document's template has the below mentioned first 4 steps, but in totality the equivalent of the what you will need to (as in portal) is:

1. Creating Log Analytics workspace. ARM Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/2015-11-01-preview/workspaces
2. Creating Automation Account. ARM Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/2015-10-31/automationaccounts
3. Linking Automation account & Log Analytics workspace. ARM Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/2015-11-01-preview/workspaces/linkedservices
4. Install OMS/LA Solution like Update Management. ARM Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/templates/microsoft.operationsmanagement/2015-11-01-preview/solutions
5. Onboarding machine to OMS/LA solution via VM extensions. ARM Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2019-07-01/virtualmachines/extensions
   Sample usage for [VM extension for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows) and [VM extension for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-linux) is additionally available.

Perhaps I am missing something but based on the information provided by you, I believe that you have missed above mentioned steps 3 and 4. So I suggest you to first complete steps 3 and 4 and then go for step 5.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, but I have already ARM templates for all listed points 1-5, I have built Automation Account, Log Analytics workspace, link them, enabled Update Management soultion in Automation Account, then installed MMA/OMS, connect VM to workspace, but there is still one manual stap to do, VM onboarding (installing Hybrid Runbook worker). Is there any way to install this Hybrid worker using ARM templates?

Comment: ahh the key here is that it's not on-boarding to Update Management specifically, but just the Log Analytics workspace, which then makes it available for Update Management